# how to get the world position of the screen corner?

Tags: screen, viewport, unreal-engine4

my game is fullscreen in mobile. How can I get the world position in 3D of the scrren corner in gold view? because I want to get the visible area in the plane(0, 0, 1).

```
// viewport size
const FVector2D viewportSize =  FVector2D(GEngine->GameViewport->Viewport->GetSizeXY());

FVector2D vecLeftUp;
vecLeftUp.X = 0.0f;
vecLeftUp.Y = 0.0f;

UGameplayStatics::DeprojectScreenToWorld(PlayerCtl, screenPt, worldOrigin, worldDirection);
```

then projection to my plane

```
FVector PlaneOrigin = FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
FVector PlaneNormal = FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

unreal engine 4 version:4.18

how can I transform the position from viewport to the screen position, maybe other way to corrent the offset?

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[ViewportToVirtualDesktopPixel](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/FViewport/ViewportToVirtualDesktopPixel/index.html)

I think thats how unreal engine doing it , try it out.